# Is it possible to simplify a series of String.replace operations?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to simplify this function? Out of the last 270 characters of code, only 50 are unique to their respective statements. Very inelegant. No jQuery please- I'd rather have a vanilla Javascript solution. Thanks so much!

```
function numbersToLetters(number) {
    var n = number.toString();
    var l = n.replace('1', 'One');
    l = l.replace('2', 'Two');
    l = l.replace('3', 'Three');
    l = l.replace('4', 'Four');
    l = l.replace('5', 'Five');
    l = l.replace('6', 'Six');
    l = l.replace('7', 'Seven');
    l = l.replace('8', 'Eight');
    l = l.replace('9', 'Nine');
    l = l.replace('0', 'Zero');
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this is "vanilla Javascript".

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what Code Review is for :)

Comment: @Qix I think he meant he doesn't want anyone to post an answer using a library/framework.

Comment: @ajp15243 Aha, that'd make sense.

Comment: FWIW, consider that the code fails on duplicate numbers such as an input of `1111` which results in `One111`.

Answer (score 8):

You could create a map:

```
var map = {
  "1" : "One",
  "2" : "Two",
  ...
}

function numbersToLetters(number) {
  var l = "" + number;
  for(var num in map){
    if(!map.hasOwnProperty(num)) continue;
    l = l.replace(num, map[num]);
  }
  return l;
}
```

Comment: While this is the base approach I would take it should be noted that, just like the original, it won't replace duplicate numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var map = ['Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four',
  'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine'];

function numbersToLetters(number) {
  number = number.toString();
  var string = '';
  for(var l in number) {
    string += map[number[l]] || number[l];
  }
  return string;
}

alert(numbersToLetters('1 and 2'));
```

This supports strings of mixed content.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a list:

```
var replacementList = [
   "Zero" ,
   "One" ,
   "Two" ,
   "Three" ,
   "Four" ,
   "Five" ,
   "Six" ,
   "Seven" ,
   "Eight" ,
   "Nine"
];

function numbersToLetters(number) {
   var numberString = number.toString();
   for (var i = 0; i < replacementList.length; i++) {
      numberString.replace(i, replacementList[i]);
   }
   return numberString;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please not your request is not just refactoring, there is a problem

> FWIW, consider that the code fails on duplicate numbers such as an input of 1111 which results in One111. –  [user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840573/is-it-possible-to-simplify-a-series-of-string-replace-operations#comment36686109_23840573)

which can be solved easily if using a loop (`for`,`while`...), but more simply:

- by using [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- with a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for the first parameter on which you can set the global flag: `/\d/g`
- the second parameter can also be a function that returns the replacement string.

Here is the example:

```
function numbersToLetters(number) {

    var n = '' + number, r = {
        '1': 'One',
        '2': 'Two',
        '3': 'Three',
        '4': 'Four',
        '5': 'Five',
        '6': 'Six',
        '7': 'Seven',
        '8': 'Eight',
        '9': 'Nine',
        '0': 'Zero'
    };

    return n.replace(/\d/g, function (matched) {
        return r[matched];
    });

}
```